# Converting Tokenize2 JSON Searchfunction from PHP into Python

Tags: python, php, jquery, json, django

Hey I'm trying to convert a searchfunction code written in PHP from a Jquery Plugin called Tokenizer2 into Python. These are 2 Links to the Plugin:
https://dragonofmercy.github.io/Tokenize2/config.html 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Tag-Input-Plugin-For-jQuery-Tokenize2.html (there is the PHP code from)

I have tested everything with PHP locally and it is working fine.

I need this Plugin to put Userinput into Tokens (obviously) and because I'm using a Django backend I'm trying to convert the following PHP-Code (which is used to search a JSON for the userinput) into python, but I'm having some problems doing so.

So this is the PHP-Code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/json');

$search = preg_quote(isset($_REQUEST['search']) ? $_REQUEST['search'] : ''); 
$start = (isset($_REQUEST['start']) ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 1;
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('tagginglist.json'), true);
$ret = array();

foreach($obj as $item)
{
    if(preg_match('/' . ($start ? '^' : '') . $search . '/i', $item['text']))
    {
        $ret[] = array('value' => $item['text'], 'text' => $item['text']);
    }
}

echo json_encode($ret);
```

And this is my attempt convert this into python:

```
import re
import request
import json

r = request.head('tagginglist.py')
search = re.escape(request['search'])
start = request['start']

x = request.get('tagginglist.py')

obj = x.json()
ret = {}


for item in obj:
    if re.match (re.compile('/' + (start '^' : '')) + search + '\i', item['text']))
        ret = {'value' : item['text'], 'text' = item['text']}

y = json.dumps(ret)
print(y)
```

My IDE is telling me that somthing if wrong in this line:

```
if re.match (re.compile('/' + (start '^' : '')) + search + '\i', item['text']))
```

and if I'm using the Form on my website I get a console Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Tokenize2.<anonymous> (tokenize2.js:630)
    at Object.e [as success] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
(anonymous) @   tokenize2.js:630
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
j   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
x   @   jquery.min.js:4
b   @   jquery.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
send    @   jquery.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   tokenize2.js:624
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   tokenize2.js:677
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)      
Tokenize2.debounce  @   tokenize2.js:685
Tokenize2.dataSourceRemote  @   tokenize2.js:620
Tokenize2.find  @   tokenize2.js:608
(anonymous) @   tokenize2.js:112
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
trigger @   jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js:3
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
trigger @   jquery.min.js:3
Tokenize2.trigger   @   tokenize2.js:98
Tokenize2.keyup @   tokenize2.js:528
(anonymous) @   tokenize2.js:123
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
trigger @   jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js:3
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
trigger @   jquery.min.js:3
Tokenize2.trigger   @   tokenize2.js:98
(anonymous) @   tokenize2.js:147
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
```

I'm really no PHP or Python expert, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a ternary operator with a missing question mark? start ? '^' : ''

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Sorry i do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I thought you was trying to write a ternary operator which is a shortcut for an if-else statement. Instead of typing if(start) { return '^' } else { return '' } you can type something like return start ? '^' : ''; I can see a missing question mark after start in your python code (line 16).

Comment: i thought the "?" is just to check if start is empty or not.

Comment: It isn't. Read more about ternary operators. They are useful in your case. You need both '?' and ':' signs. block of code following the '?' is the 'then' of the if statement and block of code following the ':' is the 'else'.